# What's the modern equivalent of ComponentMetaFactory?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, metadata

I'm using Web 8.5 and trying to construct a content delivery query to extract the schema of a given component. In older versions of Tridion, I'd have used a ComponentMetaFactory to get the ComponentMeta of the item and then used the ComponentMeta API to get the schema.

Looking at the API documentation, these classes don't seem to be there any more. The closest-sounding classes seem to come in packages related to transportpackage, so that's probably not what I want either.

So given that I've already got a query that will give me the ID of the component I'm interested in, how can I further query the API to get the item's metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you’re talking about .NET or Java, but `ComponentMetaFactory` still exists. See, for example, its usage in DXA 1.8: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.8/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs

Comment: I'm working in java. I've seen a generic method that casts to a binary or a page, but not a component.

Comment: Prompted by the fact that it's still there in .NET, I've looked again. ComponentMeta and ComponentMetaFactory are there in the implementation, and present in the .NET documentation. They aren't deprecated either, so I think this is just a documentation bug.